# Magento 2.4.0 Duplicated Site 404 Error On Some CSS And JS

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I duplicated a Magento 2.4.0 install to a dev server and I'm having a 404 issue on the CSS and JS when loading any pages on the new sub-domain and the front and back end are displaying no CSS.

[image]

So Far I have tried:

> Edited my app/etc/env.php to use the correct DB credentials
>
> Check root and pub/static for .htaccess (And replaced with fresh from Magento docs and Github)
>
> Changed web/secure/base_url and web/unsecure/base_url to match domain name including the ending /
>
> Ran the following commands

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
php bin/magento cache:disable
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB -f
```

I feel like I've read every thread even slightly related to my problem and I still can't find any solutions

Comment: did you check whether the requested files actually exist on your machine?

Comment: also, is the domain seen in the console error from your printscreen the correct one? or is the request pointing to the old machine/ old url?

Comment: @DianaBotean The files are in my pub/static/_cache/merged, I did wonder regarding the URL for the content as our content is on an AWS instance but the rest of the site is working fine and both URLs (test. and production) point towards the same URL

Comment: hmmm, ok... did you also check permissions and if the webserver is set to allow symlinks?